# How to create subcolumns in RadGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, telerik

I have 2 RadGridViews. A GridView with packages and a GridView with detail information.

I use Winforms and the RadGridView of Telerik.

I have source like this

```
private void CreatePackages()
{
    var datasource =  from s in Something....;

    gvPackages.Columns["colType"].IsVisible = false;

    gvPackages.GroupDescriptors.Clear();
    if ((int)cbddlPackageType.SelectedValue == -1)
    {
        GroupDescriptor descriptorType = new GroupDescriptor();
        descriptorSoort.GroupNames.Add("colType", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        gvPackages.GroupDescriptors.Add(descriptorType);
    }

    gvPackages.DataSource = datasource;
}

...

private void gvPackages_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenDetails(CurrentId);
}
```

[image: Current situation]

I want to create a grid with the detail information in the same gridview
How do you do that?

Like this:

[image: Situation I want to have]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a bit too late I guess. Anyway, maybe this helps some other devlopers facing the same problem.

I think you're looking for Templates. You could add a template in two ways:

1st (in designer):

Click on the three dots in your `RadGridView.Templates` property.

[image: Templates]

And then click on "Add".

[image: Add Template]

2nd (programmatically):

```
GridViewTemplate template = new GridViewTemplate();
radGridView1.Templates.Add(template);
```

Now once you have added your template to your `RadGridView`, you can use it with its index like:

```
GridViewTemplate myTemplate = radGridView1.Templates[0];
```

Now you can use it as a "normal" `RadGridView` and e.g. set its `DataSource` property.

```
myTemplate.DataSource = lFooBar;
```